# Java servlet async context existential enquiry

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, asynchronous

I just noticed when writing code in my servlet that this is valid:

```
request.getAsyncContext().getRequest().getAsyncContext()
       .getRequest().getAsyncContext()...
```

How is this possible and what does this all mean?

Comment: This means `request` i.e. of type `ServletRequest` has a public method called `getAsyncContext()` which returns the type `AsyncContext` which in turn has a method called `getRequest()` which returns a `ServletRequest` !

Comment: What's wrong in it? It's valid. Not clear what you want to acheive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have a bidirectional relation there. 
`request.getAsyncContext().getRequest()` basically returns the same Request object than 'request'

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

The class `ServletRequest` has a method `getAsynContext()` that returns the asynchronous context. The class `AsynContext` has a method `getRequest()` that returns a `ServletRequest`, which can be use to call `getAsynContext()`... So you can call those methods infinitely.